# FnOnce closures that capture an outer variable

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a function that will initialize `n` threads based on their index:

```
use std::iter::FromIterator;
use std::marker::{Send};
use std::thread::{JoinHandle, spawn};

// spawn n threads, initialized with their index
fn nspawn_i<F, T>(n: usize, f: F) -> Vec<JoinHandle<T>>
where
    F: Fn(usize) -> T,
    F: Send,
    T: Send {

    // spawn the i'th thread
    let spawn_i = |mut i: usize| -> JoinHandle<T> {
        spawn(move || f(i))
    };

    Vec::from_iter((0..n).map(spawn_i))
}
```

However, I get an error

```
error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `FnMut` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`
  --> src/main.rs:13:19
   |
13 |     let spawn_i = |mut i: usize| -> JoinHandle<T> {
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `FnMut`
14 |         spawn(move || f(i))
   |               ------- closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `f` out of its environment
...
17 |     Vec::from_iter((0..n).map(spawn_i))
   |                           --- the requirement to implement `FnMut` derives from here
```

I don't understand why `spawn_i` is `FnOnce`, and not `FnMut`, since the argument is mutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why spawn_i is FnOnce, and not FnMut, since the argument is mutable.

The argument is not relevant, closure classifications is based on what they close over and how.

Here, the issue is that `spawn_i` consumes `f` when called:

- when `spawn_i` is created, `f` is moved into it
- when `spawn_i` is called the first time, it creates the sub-closure *and `f` is moved into that*
- the second time `spawn_i` would be called... it can't be because there's no `f` to move into the sub-closure anymore

therefore `spawn_i` can only be called once.

So you need `f` to be *reusable* somehow e.g. store it in an `Arc`, or make it a function pointer (`fn(usize) -> T`) instead of a trait bound, or maybe play around with lifetimes.